# Can Fire Storm be used against flying creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight

Can the cleric level 7 spell *fire storm* be used against creatures/humanoids that are flying say 50' off the ground or can it only be used against creatures on the ground?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a "100-foot cube", meaning that it can reach up to 100' without leaving the ground. What's more, it's "centered on a point within range" (100' of the caster), allowing a creature up to 150' directly above the caster to be affected. If the caster is also flying, the effective maximum altitude is unlimited.

Comment: Ignoring Pythagoris

Comment: @DaleM: Who's ignoring Pythagoras? "Directly" above the caster needs no weird triangular solutions: just add half the cube size to the full range and there you go. (If you're trying to attack someone 80' away horizontally and ... 20' up or something, *then* you'd have to do the full trigonometric calculation.)